# pmatrix without changing font size

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fontsize, matrices

In Plain TeX with the `amstex` package, is there a way to tell `\pmatrix` to NOT change font size?

E.g. when I do:

```
\sum_{\pmatrix a \\ b \\ c \endpmatrix}
```

I end up having to insert `\scriptstyle` three times in front of the a, the b, and the c.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\everymath={\scriptstyle}` to change to `\scriptstyle`

[image]

```
$\sum_{\everymath={\scriptstyle} \pmatrix {a \cr b \cr c }}$ (With scriptstyle)

\bigskip
$\sum_{\pmatrix {a \cr b \cr c }}$  (Without scriptstyle)

\bye
```

Note that the `\everymath={\scriptstyle} \` is within a `{}` group and hence its effect are local to that group.

Also, I am not a TeX expert, and could not get your syntax to compile as your provided, so had to adapt it, so if this does not work for you, please provide [a full MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1):

there's a `\smallmatrix` meant for use in text; it sets the baselines closer together as well as making the letters smaller.  (in @Peter's example, the baselines don't change, so the letters are equally far apart even though they are different sizes.)  you *do* have to include the parentheses yourself:

```
$\sum_{\left(\smallmatrix a \\ b \\ c \endsmallmatrix\right)}$
```